# Why my Kubernetes pod network traffic does not go through the iptables NAT table?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, iptables, nat

I need to write a iptables rule in the K8s pod to SNAT packets based on some conditions but the network traffic never go through NAT table

Comment: Which CNI are you using? What did you do so far?

Comment: @chresse GKE CNI, the cluster is on GCP. I added the cap NET_ADMIN and NET_RAW to the container. I would like to SNAT some packets coming from a tap (openvpn) interface installed on the container, to change source address but packets never go in iptables nat table. I wrote some other rules in filter table and they work good. Pod is in a statefulset

Answer (score 2):

**Why my Kubernetes pod network traffic does not go through the iptables NAT table?**

Ans :

Because Kubernetes Dictates so to all CNI.
Following is from [Kubernetes Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#the-kubernetes-network-model)

```
Kubernetes imposes the following fundamental requirements on any networking 
implementation (barring any intentional network segmentation policies):

- pods on a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes without NAT
- agents on a node (e.g. system daemons, kubelet) can communicate with all pods on 
  that node. 
  Note: For those platforms that support Pods running in the host network 
  (e.g. Linux):
  - pods in the host network of a node can communicate with all pods on all nodes 
    without NAT
```